# thin wire on high tension cable

Tags: surge-protection, lightning

if the thin wire is use for protection from lightning strike in high tension tower, then tell me that how a thin wire can withstand a high voltage lightning strike.It must be melt when light strike on it before it protect other cable or tower from lightning strike.

Comment: That wire is thicker than it looks. It might be much thinner than the power transmission wires (which are thick for different reasons), but it's still heavy enough to carry the current from a lightning strike.

Comment: See Engineering.SE: [Why doesn't a lightning strike destroy the lightning rod?](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/why-doesnt-a-lightning-strike-destroy-the-lightning-rod)

Comment: See my answer at http://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/1790/624 for a analysis of why lighting won't destroy a particular size copper conductor.

Answer (score 1):

High voltage will not melt a cable.

High current will - but only if applied for long enough.

A lightning strike can result in tens of thousand amps but only for very short duration in the order of 30 µs.

See [Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning) on Wikipedia.